# How to check if a variable in one array exists in another and how to replace it in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm asking for input and then asking which words does the user want to redact. Then trying to print out the string with the words redacted.

```
puts "Input please"
text = gets.chomp
puts "What would you like redacted, sir? Type DONE when nothing else to redact"

redact = Array.new
answer = gets.chomp
until answer.downcase == "done"
  redact << answer.downcase
  answer = gets.chomp
end

words = text.split (" ")
words.each do |word|
  if word.include? (# An array to redact)
    # Replace words here 
    print "REDACTED "
  else 
    print word + " "
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
words.map {|word| redact.include?(word) ? 'REDACTED' : word}
```

This will iterate over each of the elements in your `words` array, and look to see if the element is in the `redact` array. If it is, it changes its value to `'REDACT'`, else it keeps the word the same.

Note that this will create a new array, so you will probably want to assign it to a new variable. If you want to edit the `words` array in place, you can use the `map!` function.

```
boolean ? true_path : false_path
```

is called a ternary, it is just short for

```
if boolean
  true_path
else
  false_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it one way!!

```
 words.each do |word|
   if redact.include?(word) 

#IF THE ARRAY REDACT INCLUDES VARIABLE WORD, PRINT REDACT

 print "REDACTED "
   else print word + " "
   end
 end
```